# Small caps in fontspec on XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, small-caps

I'm trying to typeset my document with Times with XeLaTeX.
Because Times does not include small caps,
I want to use TeX Gyre Termes only for small caps.
I tried [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135645/44901),
but it didn't work.
A warning is issued and the output is not small caps.

The question:

- What is wrong?
- How can I do this?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{Times}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\textsc{Hello!}
\end{document}
```

and the warning:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Letters=SmallCaps' (3,3) not available in font 'TeX Gyre
* Termes'.
*************************************************
```

What I've tried:

- I tried typesetting with LuaLaTeX and the result was fine with no warnings.
- I replaced `Times` with `Times New Roman` and there was no problem.
- I added `Renderer=ICU` and the warning changed to `icu-feature-not-exist-in-font`.
  It seems that fontspec can use `.dfont` with ICU?
- I replaced `Times` with another `.dfont` font `Helvetica Neue` and the problem disappeared.
  Thus not all `.dfont` font cause the problem....

I'm using MacTeX 2013 on OS X Mountain Lion.

**Update**

Following a suggestion from @KhaledHosny,
I tried adding `\the\XeTeXfonttype\font` before and after `\textsc{`,
and both returned `1` (AAT font).
With `Render=ICU` they returned `2` (OpenType font), but I got no small caps.
It seems that XeTeX can treat Times as OpenType, but even then `SmallCapsFeatures` doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked if there's a font provided by the OS that's called `Times`? XeLaTeX will work with system-installed fonts, while LuaLaTeX searches for fonts more broadly.

Comment: @Mico Yes. Both `Times` and `TeX Gyre Termes` are listed in `Font Book.app`.

Comment: I have no problem with my version of the Times: `Times New Roman PS Std`. However, my Times version has also Small Caps, the reason why I do not need the TeX Gyre Termes. But it also works with the small caps from Termes.

Comment: @Herbert The Times I'm using is the version preinstalled on OS X.

Comment: The “Times” font is in `.dfont` format and apparently `fontspec` is not able to use it other than with the AAT renderer, which is not available for TeX Gyre Termes; you should also have a `Times New Roman.ttf` in `/Library/Fonts` and on my system the combination works.

Comment: @egreg I have `Times New Roman`, and with it there is no problem. But I want to use `Times`, not `Times New Roman`. If `fontspec` can use `Times` only with the AAT renderer, why is there no problem when typeset with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Looks like your Times is an AAT font which causes `fontspec` to process all features as AAT features (including the `SmallCapsFeatures`) but TeX Gyre Termes as an OpenType font so this does not work.

Comment: @KhaledHosny How can I check the type of a font? All I know is that my Times has `.dfont` extension.

Comment: While the font is active, `\the\XeTeXfonttype\font` should print the type of the font engine XeTeX choses for this font (0 for TFM fonts, 1 for AAT, 2 for OpenType and 3 for Graphite).

Comment: @KhaledHosny Thanks for the instruction. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found that this can be achieved with NFSS.

First, Times and TeX Gyre Termes are loaded separately.
Then the definition of small caps of Times in NFSS is overwritten so that it redirects to small caps of TeX Gyre Termes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}

\newfontfamily\tgtermes{TeX Gyre Termes}
\makeatletter
  \begingroup
    \tgtermes
    \DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\rmdefault}{m}{sc}{%
      <-> ssub * \f@family/m/sc}{}
    \DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\rmdefault}{bx}{sc}{%
      <-> ssub * \f@family/bx/sc}{}
  \endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello!
\textsc{Hello!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a clever workaround. I've been aware for some time that the `Renderer` option was somewhat restrictive in that it applies to all individual fonts in a "family"… but this is the first time that someone's bumped into a limitation `:)` I'll keep it in mind next time I'm updating `fontspec`.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe the easiest way is as follows:

In the example, **Crimson Text** does  not have smallcaps, but **Crimson** does. (The scale used here has only to do with better-looking output in this case.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Crimson Text}

\newfontinstance\scshape[Letters=SmallCaps,Scale=1.15]{Crimson}

\begin{document}
Text \textsc{Text}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE as noted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732/whatever-happened-to-newfontinstance), `\newfontinstance` no longer works, replaced with `\newfontfamily`.

Comment: I really can't make this work, even with `\renewfontfamily` which seems required now.