# Small caps in parbox

Tags: small-caps

Let me get to the point:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newlength\longest
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\settowidth\longest{\huge\itshape just as his inclination leads him;}
\begin{flushright}{
\parbox{\longest}{%
  {\huge\itshape%
 \begin{flushright}
  Influenza is something unique. It behaves epidemiologically in a way different from that of any other known infection.
 \end{flushright}\par\bigskip
  }   
  \raggedleft\Large\textsc{Sir Christopher Howard Andrewes}\par%
}}\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

the `\textsc` won't make "Margaret Chan" in small caps, though... Can anyone help me?

Extra note: pretty convinced of it that Times New Roman supports small caps ;)

Comment: If the font family you use doesn't provide small caps, how can (Xe|Lua)LaTeX print them?

Comment: `TeX Gyre Termes` is times-like with small caps

Comment: [Hi and Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A little hint, if you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). ;-)

Comment: Found the answer thanks to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165998/small-caps-in-fontspec-on-xelatex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Times New Roman doesn't come with small caps, if you look in the log file you will see a message to that effect.  You can provide small caps from a similar font as follows:

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Times New Roman}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newlength\longest
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

\settowidth\longest{\huge\itshape just as his inclination leads him;}

\begin{flushright}{
  \parbox{\longest}{%
  {\huge\itshape%
  \begin{flushright}
    Influenza is something unique. It behaves epidemiologically in a
    way different from that of any other known infection.  
  \end{flushright}
  \par\bigskip
  }
  \raggedleft\Large\textsc{Sir Christopher Howard Andrewes}\par%
  }}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```