# Small caps issue with Xelatex

Tags: fontspec

### Problem

I've just bought Baskerville Classico font and tried to load it using Xelatex, but small caps didn't work. I finally found this post : [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165998/small-caps-in-fontspec-on-xelatex]... added this piece of code and loaded it with LuaLaTex and it works:

```
    \setmainfont[
  SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{Baskerville Classico}
```

Is my preamble correct?

This is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[
  SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{Baskerville Classico}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[CE]{\textsc{A title}} % even pages: chapter title
    \fancyhead[CO]{\textsc\leftmark} % odd pages: book title
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \chapter{A title}
    \lipsum
    
    \end{document}
```

### Solution

Finally, I found the solution. This is the piece of code to add instead of Tex Gyre Termes:

```
\setmainfont[
  SmallCapsFont={BaskervilleClassicoSC},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{Baskerville Classico}
```

Comment: If you do that, you won’t get Barkerville Classico’s small caps. You’re substituting a Times clone. I don’t own that font to test, but does `otfinfo -f` say it supports the Small Caps feature? Or does the family have small caps as a separate face?

Comment: Otfinfo : otfinfo -f Baskerville Classico
otfinfo: Baskerville: No such file or directory
otfinfo: Classico: No such file or directory

Comment: Small caps work well in Word, for instance.

Comment: `otfinfo` needs the file and path, which you should be able to find with `luaotfload-tool --find "Baskerville Classico"`.

Comment: This is what I get: luaotfload | resolve : Font "Baskerville Classico" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/Library/Fonts/Linotype - Baskerville Classico.otf"

Comment: Okay, so check `otfinfo -f "/Library/Fonts/Linotype - Baskerville Classico.otf"` and look for `smcp`.

Comment: You can also look for another Small Caps face in the same directory.

Comment: I've got this one: Linotype - Baskerville Classico SC.otf

Comment: OK, then this might work: `SmallCapsFont={Linotype - Baskerville Classico SC.otf}`. You should not need `SmallCapsFeatures`.

Comment: It doesn't work when I try to compile with this code: \setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Linotype - Baskerville Classico SC.otf}]{Baskerville Classico}: no more headings and no small caps.

Comment: I don’t have the font to test. But you aren’t getting errors about the font not loading? Does the SC font actually have small caps?

Comment: Yes, it does. But it is found by Xelatex. Double Bounty for any help!

Comment: Do I have to put the font in the Mac Tex directory (if only I can)?

Comment: The font should work if it’s in your system font book. I believe MacTeX doesn’t search your user directory. You normally don’t manually want to change your MacTeX directory, but you can create a new local TeX tree using the MacTeX console and put files there.

Comment: However, you say that XeTeX is finding the font, so that shouldn’t be the issue. If you could edit what you’re trying to do and what messages you’re getting in your `.log` file, that might help.

Comment: Is this an interesting warning? LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/BaskervilleClassico(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/BaskervilleClassico(0)/m/n' instead on input line 108.

Comment: Yes, and it’s odd; it implies that XeTeX is looking for the non-SC font. You might try `SmallCapsFeatures = {}` along with `SmallCapsFont` to make explicit that it should not attempt to look for a `smcp` feature in the SC font. Or you might see if LuaLaTeX works with it.

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks for your help @Davislor. I've just started a bounty.

Comment: better use `\textsc{\leftmark}` with braces. Beside this: Show the complete (!) log-file of your MWE (!) compiled with lualatex (!) (but I don't understand why you try to use termes as small caps font).

Comment: Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Numbers=Lowercase' (onum) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'Baskerville Classico' with
(fontspec)                script 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.

Comment: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/BaskervilleClassico(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/BaskervilleClassico(0)/m/n' instead on input line 116.

Comment: When I use BaskervilleClassicoSC instead of Baskerville Classico as \setmainfont, small caps work. Any idea of how to use small caps in headings???

Comment: I just solved my problem by myself. How to edit that question in order to mark it as solved (and... keep my bounty...)?

Comment: I guess that you can provide an answer to your own question or it can be closed?! Can you cancel the bounty? As of now, I cannot vote to close because of the active bounty.

Comment: afaik, bounty prizes are nonrefundable, and expiration dates nonnegotiable. What may work is for @Davislor to provide an answer, because it seems to me that he gave the op the clue to solve his problem, and then award that bounty to that answer.

Comment: @Davislor: thanks for your help. You deserve my bounty.

Comment: I don’t know what the solution actually was, though!

Comment: @Davislor The OP updated the answer with the solution (at the bottom). And +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ll migrate my advice, which the OP confirms was helpful, into an answer rather than the comments.

By default, `fontspec` tries to activate the feature it calls `Letters=SmallCaps` and OpenType calls `smcp`.  You can check whether a given font has this feature with the command `otfinfo -f`, followed by the absolute filename with its path. You can get the filename from the display name of the font with `luaotfload-tool --find`.  You typically want to put names that contain spaces in double quotes on the command line.

In this case, you told me that the filename was `/Library/Fonts/Linotype - Baskerville Classico.otf`, and that it did not have this feature.  There was, however, another font face in the same directory that did have small caps, `Linotype - Baskerville Classico SC.otf`.

Typically, you would load a separate small-caps face like this by adding options like

```
\defaultfontfeatures[BaskervilleClassico]{
  % Set Ligatures, Numbers, etc.
  SmallCapsFont={* SC},
  SmallCapsFeatures={} }

\setmainfont{BaskervilleClassico}
```

If there’s also a bold or italic small caps face, you would load that with options like, hypothetically,

```
  ItalicFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = {*-SC-Italic},
                     SmallCapsFeatures = {} },
```

What methods of loading a file vary between XeTeX and LuaTeX on different OSes, but using the exact filename with `Extension=` is usually recommended.

Here, what seemed to work was the family name and style.  You can get a list of the possible family and style names that `fontspec` might understand with `otfinfo -i`, and test whether LuaTeX can look up a name with `luaotfload-tool --find` or whether XeTeX can look it up with `fc-match`.