# Polyglossia + Times New Roman font : small capitals not working

Tags: fonts, polyglossia, small-caps

I'm using the polyglossia package with Times New Roman font. Everything is working, all caracters are displayed well, except for the small capitals... I tried different fonts like Arial, Arial Unicode MS, etc. but it small capitals are never working, except when I don't specify the font in which case not all caracters are displayed. 
What can I do to make the small capitals work ?

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{book}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{slantsc}

    \usepackage{fontspec,xgreek}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{french}
    \setotherlanguages{english,german,italian,latin,spanish,russian}

     \begin{document}

     En ce qui concerne le sémantisme, autant en pré-protoroman qu'en protoroman, le suffixe */-'ur-a/ désigne généralement une action et son effet : 

    \begin{itemize}
        \item */kʊnsu't-ur-a/ s.f. « action de coudre ; assemblage de deux morceaux d'étoffe cousus ensemble, couture »
        \item */Φrik't-ur-a/ s.f. « action de cuire certains aliments à la poêle, le résultat de la cuisson »
        \item */mʊli't-ur-a/ s.f. « action de moudre une céréale ; revenu qu'obtient le meunier pour la céréale moulue »
        \item */ordi't-ur-a/ s.f. «  le résultat de l'ourdissage ; structure ; longueur de la chaîne d'une étoffe, ourdissage » 
    \end{itemize}

    lat. \textsc{cooper\={\i}m\u{e}ntum}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135645/4427

Comment: And for more background: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302597/how-to-write-bold-italic-and-sans-serif-at-the-same-time/302601#302601

Comment: @ebo Your answer is good, but it is not very helpful in this case since it is based on the traditional font set up. For example, once you load `fontspec` or `polyglossia`, Computer Modern Roman is *not* the default if you don't specify a font family.